# Video is running but shows only black screen in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have created a folder called `raw` and added `tutorial.mp4` and trying to run it on the `VideoView`.

I could able to see the duration of the video but video is all black, it does not show the actual video .

I am running on Xamarin Android Player emulator. I wonder I am missing?

```
using Uri = Android.Net.Uri;


var videoView = view.FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.myVideo);
var uri = Uri.Parse("android.resource://" + this.Activity.BaseContext.PackageName  + "/raw/tutorial");
videoView.SetVideoURI(uri);
videoView.Start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the video is black (but you might actual hear the audio), then the emulator does not support the codec your video are using.

Use a real device or use a different emulator (Google's AVD w/ Intel Haxm, Visual Studio's Android Player, Genymotion).

FYI: Xamarin Android Player (XAP) has been deprecated for some time now...

VideoView from a **raw** Resource:

```
var uri = Uri.Parse("android.resource://" + PackageName + "/" + Resource.Raw.B);
videoView.SetVideoURI(uri);
```

Comment: I could not able to hear the audio of the video. I am using Windows 7, therefore, I cannot able to add Visual Studio Android Player.

Comment: I have tried the Genymotion, and it shows `"cannot play this video"`

Comment: I even tried youtube link on the Genymotion but it still shows `"cannot play this video"`

Comment: If you are getting `cannot play this video` (assuming that message is in an Alert popup dialog), try a different `.mp4`, not all play with VideoView (I have to re-encode a large number of H.264-based videos to play properly).

Comment: @hotspring youtube link? You are getting the raw `.mp4` link from a youtube video page? FYI: This would be a violation of their TOS if you are trying to bypass their HTML player.

Comment: I am calling it via             `videoView.SetVideoURI(Uri.Parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpPXrwjgdSU"));`

Comment: @hotspring That is a HTML link for their HTML player, use a WebView and it would work, but not a VideoView.

Comment: Since my ultimate goal is to play local video; therefore, I need to stick with `VideoView`, I just wanted to test quickly with youtube link. Which video extension you recommend for either `genymotion` or `xap` to play?

Comment: Grab the big buck bunny mp4 trailer as a test video.... : http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html

Comment: Thanks a lot SushilHangover. Finally, without any code changes, I could able to see the video.